# What are the drawbacks to setting Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel" for all pages?

Tags: asp.net, cross-browser

We've run into problems recently because as of Firefox 4's release, ScrollPosition data never gets sent to Firefox users. This is caused by the browsercaps file only specifying capabilities for Firefox 3.x. One solution to this problem is to update the browsercaps file on every server, and any time a new version of Firefox (or Chrome, or whatever) is released. Well, before we've even had a chance to address this problem, we're already on Firefox 6, and it just seems like a race that we don't want to keep running.

It turns out that setting Page.ClientTarget = "uplevel" in the master page (so, for everything, unconditionally) fixes our specific Firefox ScrollPosition issue. What are the negative consequences to this as a solution? Are users of Android browsers going to have a worse experience? Are they simply going to be downloading unnecessarily larger pages now? Is there any reason we shouldn't do this?

The documentation for Page.ClientTarget is pretty scary:

> uplevel , which specifies browser capabilities equivalent to Internet
>   Explorer 6.0.

.. and seems wrong, or at least misleading. It seems like it was written at a time when IE6 was the most capable browser. Does "uplevel" really mean "assume the browser is capable of everything" or "treat it like you'd treat IE6"?

Comment: firefox current release is 6.0. check if this issue persists

Comment: Yes, it persists. There is nothing Firefox can do to fix the problem other than to change its version number back to something less than 4. The browsercaps file (which we have never touched) only specifies Firefox versions prior to 4 as an uplevel browser.

Comment: +1 for an antique MSDN link. They should really update that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to tell WebForms to effectively "lay off" then setting Uplevel works, although you want to do it in Page_Init which is earlier than the Master Page. At this point, WebForms will assume everyone is a newer browser than you're on your own.

Answer (score 1):

For server-side compatibility, which can't test the browser's actual limitations, I prefer using a blacklist instead of a whitelist: if a browser isn't known to **not** support feature X then I assume it supports it.

You can also blacklist all versions of a browser, e.g. no version of IE supports feature X). this requires you to update the blacklist once IE does support feature X.

Browser upgrades shouldn't break this scheme.

Comment: What mechanism do you use to implement your blacklist?

Comment: What are some examples of features you disable explicitly for certain browsers in your blacklist? What would be the consequence of leaving those features enabled?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the "what are the drawbacks" question, but:

You can use regular expressions in the browser version detection within the browsercaps files.

For example, on November 13, 2011 Microsoft released an update for ASP.NET 4.0 that added IE10 to the uplevel list (and fixed a bug in the `ie.browser` file, located in `\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\Browsers`). They had a regular expression that only checked for single-digit major version, but after the patch any IE version >= 6 will be considered uplevel.

Before the change:

```
<capability name="majorversion" match="[6-9]" />
```

After the change:

```
<capability name="majorversion" match="[6-9]|[1-9]\d+" />
```

I'm guessing you are not running into this problem any more, because at least as of 26 October 2011, the firefox directive also uses a regex to detect as uplevel versions >= 3: (from the `firefox.browser` file)

```
<browser id="Firefox3" parentID="Firefox">
    <identification>
        <capability name="majorversion" match="^[3-9]|[1-9]\d+" />
    </identification>

    <capabilities>
        <capability name="javascriptversion"               value="1.8" />
        <capability name="supportsMaintainScrollPositionOnPostback" value="true" />
    </capabilities>
</browser>
```

but if you are still having probs, just use a forward-thinking regex (one that does not have a "single digit major version" bug like in earlier patches) in the `firefox.browser` file